# JPA: Automatically create relations from JSON without having to parse manually

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I'm developing a REST API with Spring Boot and I want to use my domain class as my request object (DTO). However, if I try to save an object with child entities, hibernate isn't able to create the correct relations.

## Example

Assume the model of a Survey. Surveys contain Pages.

```
class Survey {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "path.to.package.UUIDGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "survey")
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Page {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "path.to.package.UUIDGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private UUID id;
    private String label;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")
    private Survey survey;
}
```

If I now want to create a new survey via the controller, I would do something like this

```
    @PostMapping
    public HttpEntity<SurveyDto> createSurvey(@RequestBody Survey request) {
        var s = surveyService.createSurvey(request);
        URI self = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(BASE_URL + "/{id}")
                .uriVariables(Map.of("id", s.getId()))
                .build().toUri();
        return ResponseEntity.created(self).body(s);
```

with a request that would look like this:

```
{
  "name": "survey1",
  "pages": [
    {
      "label": "First Page"
    },
    {
      "label": "Second Page"
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON parser parses it correctly, however the references are not correct, as in: `page.getSurvey()` would be `null`. Therefore, hibernate can't set the relations (or at least that's what i think is happening)

My Question now is, if it is possible to achieve something, where I can just post a Survey as JSON and then just save that object, without having to manually map the JSON to a new Survey object where I manually set the pages array, since that would be a lot of mapping I'd have to do because of multiple child entities.

(First time posting a question, so if I missed any important information, feel free to request in the comments)

Comment: Do you need the reference from Page to Survey? If not you could remove it and use @JoinColumn on the pages relationship to have a uni-directonal relationshio

Comment: Do you _have_ to use a relational database for this? With only the information and context you've given, I'd consider a different data store that understands JSON directly.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i could work around without it, however I think that this wouldnt solve my issue. The problem is that in the database, the foreign key fields are null and I think removing the page to survey reference would not influence that. I will try it tho.

Comment: In your JSON you don't have any ids at all!

Comment: @E-Riz yes, using a relational database was requested by my employer. In fact, this is actually an overhaul of an existing system that was saving surveys in just plain json files. However, at some point there should be an admin interface where new surveys can be created and also edited etc. so it makes sense to be able (for example) to insert new pages for surveys etc.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes I want to generate the Ids on the server, with the generator that is specified for the Id columns in the domain classes. Hibernate correctly generates the PK for survey and page objects but it doesnt manage to use the PK of survey as FK in page (as in the FK is null)

Comment: but this should work with a uni-directional relationship and cascading

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I tried out your suggestion of removing the page to survey relation, but I am still facing the same issue. When I check the database, survey_id in the page table is still null

Comment: and you have added cascading and @JoinColumn? Can you please update your question?

Comment: Instead of trying to think of mapping JSON to relational tables, and trying to reuse the persistent entities as DTOs (which is generally an anti-pattern), I suggest taking this as 2 different steps: creating POJOs from the JSON, with the object relationships that make sense, _then_ mapping objects to tables using Hibernate/JPA. I strongly recommend NOT using the entities as DTOs, it's going to be like swimming upstream the whole time. Jackson is good at the first step, JPA/Hibernate is good at the second. Both have lots of flexibility, but it seems you're trying to combine them.

Comment: @E-Riz thanks for the response. So you would suggest to have a mapper of sorts that maps requests to POJOs, if i understand correctly? This is what im trying to avoid, since i am exactly posting the data i need, but the more I browse the internet it seems that this is probably the option I will use, its a lot of boilerplate code in my opinion, but its probably easier to handle this in code instead of trying to fine-tune with hibernate/jpa. Thanks for the response :D

Comment: If you're using Jackson for your JSON parsing, it has a flexible set of annotations you can put on the POJOs to instruct it how to map JSON to them. See https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-deserialization-annotations

Comment: If you're using Spring (or willing to), the [Spring Data REST project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-rest) might get you 90% of the way where you're trying to get.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@JsonManagedReference` to your list and `@JsonBackReference` to the `Survey` field. As pointed out the problem is your bi-directional relationship and the fact that the owning side (`managedBy="survey")` is never set due to you sending a `Survey` and not a `Page`.

Comment: Another option is to implement the `setPages` method and when invoked iterate over the list of pages and call `page.setSurvey(this)`. So that both parts of the relationships are managed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@M. Deinum had the right clue, by adding `@JsonManagedReference`to the list and `@JsonBackReference` to the survey field, Jackson knew how to correctly parse the object and therefore created the correct references.

## Updated Example

```java
class Survey {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "path.to.package.UUIDGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private UUID id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "survey")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Page> pages = new ArrayList<>();
}

class Page {
    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name="uuid", strategy = "path.to.package.UUIDGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    private UUID id;
    private String label;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "survey_id")
    @JsonBackReference 
    private Survey survey;
}
```

Also, if you have multiple relations like these you have to give your references names with `@JsonManagedReference(value = "survey-page")` and `@JsonBackReference(value = "survey-page)`